# What is this SQL query doing on an Excel file?

Tags: sql, excel

I don't understand this code snippet. When I try another excel file it doesn't compile properly. Why did the programmer use F and is it referring to the column or row?

```
string strProvider;
        if (dbFilePath.LastIndexOf("xlsx") > -1)
            strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbFilePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";";
        else
            strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""" + dbFilePath + @""";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;""";

        string strQuery = "SELECT  " +
                            "F9 AS EmpNbr,  " +
                            "F10 AS ACCTSTATUS, " +
                            "F1  AS PROJECTEDAGE, " +
                            "F14 AS UPDBALDUE, " +
                            "F15 AS AMTCURRENT, " +
                            "F16 AS AMT30DAY, " +
                            "F17 AS AMT60DAY, " +
                            "F18 AS AMT90DAY, " +
                            "F19 AS AMT120DAY, " +
                            "F20 AS AMT150DAY, " +
                            "F21 AS AMT180DAY " +
                           "FROM [Sheet1$A8:V] " +
                           "WHERE F9 IS NOT NULL AND " +
                           "(F17 > 0 OR F18 > 0 OR F19 > 0 OR F20 > 0 OR F21 > 0) " +
                           "  AND Trim(F10) <> 'RETURN MAIL/LEFT COMPANY' " +
                           "  AND Trim(Left(F1,3)) IN ('60','90','120','150','180') " +
                           "ORDER BY F9 ";
```

Comment: Does F refer to the column?

Comment: Jet and ACE are OLEDB providers that allow you to use an SQL syntax on a Excel spreadsheet and other data in MS office. So, yes they are cell references tha are being aliased. Since you have the spreadsheet you can look in the cells and see what the data is. For instance, I suspect cell `F9` contains an Employee Number.

Comment: I thought so too but in the Excel file F9 doesn't refer to anything relevant. Actually when I transpose the data in the Excel file it makes a little more sense i.e. 9 is referring to the column and F the row... i don't know why it's like that though

Comment: I editied my answer, what is in F17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F1, F2, F3 etc` are simply generated column headings and are **NOT** cell references. Even though within the connection string you have `HDR=YES`, if the first row is blank then the provider will autogenerate column names from `F1` to `F(n)`. Why it chooses F I do not know, but `n` is simply the column ordinal (starting at 1), and the name is prefixed so it can't be confused with a number.

If you revert to thinking of your dataset as a database rather than a spreadsheet, it would not make sense to refer to a specific row in a query, e.g If you imagine a small table

```
ID | A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------
 1 | x  |  y  |  z  |
 2 | d  |  e  |  f  |
 3 | j  |  k  |  l  |
```

Then think in terms of SQL rather than excel the following query does not make sense to get just the first row because `A1` = X:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM Sheet1
WHERE A1 = 'x';
```

You would have to use columns as so:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM Sheet1
WHERE ID = 1
AND A = 'x';
```

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for. I didn't understand where the F came from since it wasn't referring to the actual cell. It seems both providers do the same thing and assign 'F' as the prefix of the column name when there are no default column names. Thanks for solving this

Answer (score 1):

F9, F10 and so on are cells , F (or any other letter/combination) being the column indicator, and 9 (or any other number) the line index.

Answer (score 0):

What this snippet is doing here, is creating an OLEDB connection to a database, and the executing a query against the database. In the beginning it is checking to see is the database is another excel sheet.  If it is then it uses this connection type:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbFilePath + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"

Otherwise it uses this:

> "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""" + dbFilePath + @""";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="

It is probably expecting any other type of database to be Access based, as my guess.

Comment: actually, its always connecting to a spreadsheet but, if the file extension is `xlsx`, it infers a new Excel version so it uses `ACE`. Otherwise it uses the older `JET` provider, summing an `xls` extension. Of course, in practice, there is only a loose relationship between file extension and file content.

Answer (score 0):

Jet and ACE are OLEDB providers that allow you to use an SQL syntax on a Excel spreadsheet and other data in MS office. So, yes they are cell references that are being aliased. Since you have the spreadsheet you can look in the cells and see what the data is. For instance, I suspect cell `F9` contains an Employee Number.

In an Excel Spreasheet, columns are enumerated from `A` through `Z`, then `AA` through `AZ` etc, rows enumerate from `1` upwards. So cell reference `F9` is coordinated at column `F` and row `9`.

---

Because the "FROM" range `Sheet1$A8:V` is relative, you might have to tarnspose the select accordingly. What is in the 17th row? Is `F17` the employee number?

---

Maybe change the query to

```
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A8:V]"
```

and start from there.

Comment: In this instance F9 doesn't refer to cell F9 in the excel spreadsheet. I didn't understand at first, but GarethD explained it below